# Is there a way to use Touch ID with the iOS Keychain but not prompt for the user passcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, ios8, keychain

I want to store user credentials securely in the iOS Keychain, but I only want the user to be able to use their fingerprint to retrieve the Keychain item. Is there a workflow for calling the Touch ID sensor to retrieve Keychain items with the ability to dismiss the passcode unlock or without falling back to the passcode at all?

I have implemented the methods defined in the WWDC session on Touch ID and Keychain, but I do not want to fall back on the device passcode like they do in their demo. I want the user to sign in traditionally once the fingerprint scan has failed.

Answer (score 6):

[@kishikawa-katsumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255307/804678) is right, in iOS 8 there is no way to disable passcode fallback. The `kSecAccessControlUserPresence` access control flag makes an item accessible after either Touch ID or Passcode authentication succeeds and it even doesn't require Touch ID to be available.

But this has been improved in iOS 9. Two Touch ID-related flags, `kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny` and `kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet`, [have been added](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/Security.html).

So, you need to use either of these two flags when creating access control object for Keychain item (with `SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags` function) and assign that object to `kSecAttrAccessControl` attribute when adding the item with `SecItemAdd` function.

There is [an example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Listings/KeychainTouchID_AAPLKeychainTestsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014530-KeychainTouchID_AAPLKeychainTestsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) that demonstrates this; see `addTouchIDItemAsync` method. Also, see [this post](https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/ios9-security-privacy/) for an overview of other security-related changes in iOS 9.

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the "Enter Password" button using `localizedFallbackTitle` property

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = @"sign in traditionally";
```

If you want to remove the fallback button, just set the property like this

```
myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable fallback mechanism using passcode in Keychain TouchID integration.

Comment: Fortunately, this has been addressed in iOS 9. Btw, thank you so much for the awesome KeychainAccess library! =)

Comment: Have you added this feature to your library??

Comment: @skozin 's answer is correct. And KeychainAccess library has already supported building the same configuration already.